# Cant get data from sql server to php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

i have a php website linked with  Sql Server database, im trying to get data from the database and show it on the page in a table but when it create the table it show me the message "No results found" , what is the code to get the info from the database and show it in the website?

ps:im using jquery.bootgrid

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';
$query='';
$data=array();
$records_per_page= 10;
$start_from= 0;
$current_page_number= 0;

if(isset($_POST["rowCount"]))
{
$records_per_page= $_POST["rowCount"];
}
else
{
$records_per_page= 10;
}

if(isset($_POST["current"]))
{
$records_per_page= $_POST["current"];
}

else
{
$records_per_page= 1;
}

$star_from= ($current_page_number - 1)* $records_per_page;

$query .="SELECT * FROM Employee";

if(!empty($_POST["searchPhrase"]))
{
$query .= 'where (Id like "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%")';
$query .= 'or First_Name like "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
$query .= 'or Last_Name like "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
$query .= 'or username like "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';

}

$order_by = '';

if(isset($_POST["sort"]) && is_array($_POST["sort"]))
{
foreach($_POST["sort"] as $key =>$value )
{
    $order_by = '$key $value,';
}
}
else
{
$query .= 'order by Id Desc';
}

if($order_by != '')
{
$query .= ' order by ' . substr($order_by,0,-2);
}

if($records_per_page != -1)
{
$query .= "LIMIT" .$star_from. "," .$records_per_page;
}




$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
$data[]=$row;
}

$query1 .="SELECT * FROM Employee";
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);
$total_records=sqlsrv_has_rows($result1);

$output=array('current'    => intval($_POST["current"]),
          'rowCount'   => 10, 
          'total'      => intval($total_records), 
          'rows'       => $data );

echo json_encode($output);             


 ?>
```

Comment: What you have tried

Comment: Please go through this before you post any any question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i put the code in the question

Comment: On lines like `$query .="SELECT`, you shouldn't have the `.=` just `=` as this adds to a previous string.  Also when you add to your `$query` make sure there is a space between the various parts, like `$query .= ' where`. Lastly - if you don't check for errors when running queries, you won't find out what the problems are.

Comment: you must print or echo your query before you fetch, make sure it has result in your databse